# Русский язык в консольной команде yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Я создал консольный контролер. В нем есть действие. В этом действии из бд достается запись в которой есть поле с русским текстом.

Как сделать, чтобы текст в консоли отображался русскими символами?

Comment: Предположу что проблема не в PHP а в настройках ОС. Хотя можно конечно конвертировать кодировку перед выводом. `iconv` `mb_convert_encoding`

Comment: Установите в консоли кодировку по умолчанию UTF-8 . Не знаю как в других, в моём любимом ZOC - можно.